# Determining which TFS process template is being used

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

How can one determining which TFS process template is being used? A few were installed and now I can't determine which one is being used by TFS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to Edward's approach:
Another one, quick & dirty and without any capability to reveal any changes you might have performed, is the following:
Right-Click on your TeamProject from within the Team Explorer and select "Team Project Process Guidance":
[image]
This should pop-up a webpage that will show you the Process Template that was used to create it.

Comment: Didn't think about that approach.  Nice and easy.

Answer (score 9):

[TFS Team Project Manager on CodePlex](http://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/) is a free tool which will inspect all your team projects process templates (even if they're customized) and tell you which process template was most likely used to create that Team Project (and give you a % confidence in the match).  You can even give it additional "source" process templates, such as your company custom process template, and it will tell you which projects were created with it.

[image: Team Project Manager Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

If you have not modified the process templates (either the ones that are included with TFS, or any that you might have downloaded and installed) then you can [export the process template as an XML file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb187321%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and compare against the original version.

(That link is really about *modifying* the process template, but steps 1-3 discuss how to export the current process template for a Team Project.)

Of course, even if you had modified the process templates slightly, using a diff tool may be able to yield results as to which process templates those were derived from.